# Mongoose find filtering by attached document

Tags: mongoose, find

I am struggling with a query using mongoose and nodejs. I am trying to get all the bookings from a provider, this provider is related to the bookings Doc by the package Doc.
I have this booking schema:

```
const bookingSchema = new Schema( {

    package: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Package',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a package must exist']
    },


    requesters: {
        type: Number,
        default: 1
    },

    status: {
        type: String
    },

});
```

And this is the package schema:

```
const packageSchema = new Schema( {


    title: {
        type: String
    },


    profile: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Profile',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a profile must exist']
    },

    service: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Service',
        required: [ true, 'A reference to a service must exist']
    },

});
```

Now I am trying to get all the booking for this provider with the profile and service related:

```
 const filter = { 
        $and: [
        {"package" : { $exists: true } }, 
        {"package.profile": ObjectId(profile._id)}
        ]
    };


return Booking.find( filter )
            .populate({
                path: 'package',
                match: {'profile' : { $exists: true}},
                model: 'Package',
                select : 'profile service',

                populate : [
                    {
                    path : 'profile',
                    model: 'Profile',
                    select : '_id name user'

                    
                    },               
                ]
            })
            .populate(
                {
                    path : 'service',
                    model: 'Service',
                    select : '_id'
                }
                 
            )
            .sort( { date: -1 } )
            .exec();
```

But I get an empty array, not results. This is the query I can see in the console.

```
Mongoose: bookings.find({ '$and': [ { package: { '$exists': true } }, { 'package.profile': ObjectId("5f2a668ccee9bd8fd7a75d29") } ]}, { sort: { date: -1 }, projection: {} })
bookings []
```

**I ONLY need the bookings for this provider, where the profile._id is equal to the provider profile I pass to the find method.**

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally I solved it doing this:

```
 const packages = await Package.find({'profile' : profile._id}).select('_id').exec();

    const ids: any = packages.map( (pkg: any) => {
        return pkg._id;
    });

 return Booking.find( {'package': {$in: ids}} ) .....
```

Is there another better solution?